# How to create a link for uploading an app to the microsoft store

Tags: upload, store

I want to upload an app to the Microsoft store. As part of this process, I need to provide them with a direct download link for my apps installer. I am having trouble doing this. I have provided them with a link to my app on google drive but the web site gave me an error when submitting. I need to know how to create a direct download link for my app.

I uploaded my installer to google drive and got a shared link for it. I then submitted this to the Microsoft store. I got back an error message saying "Package URL should begin with https:// and should point to a versioned, downloadable package."

My url begins with the https:// but after that its random letters. Is there a way to do this with google drive? Maybe someone could suggest another service that does this. Thanks.